# Best solution to implement multiple account types + registration forms in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm looking to create an app where suppliers can register as well as customers.

I want to restrict registration for suppliers so that they can only register by e-mail and not by facebook or twitter, is this possible? does anyone have any solutions or can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are wanting can certainly be built.

In Meteor, [Accounts.validateNewUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_validatenewuser) is used to pass/fail the creation of new users and [Accounts.onCreateUser()](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser) can add database fields to new users and optionally fail their creation.  You can also get access to login templates instead of leaving them hidden in the project's dot meteor directory.

Evented Mind has a pretty good [video presentation on customizing the Meteor Login system](https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/customizing-login) but it is behind a paywall. There are actually quite a few useful video HOWTOs in there.... so it may be worth their fairly reasonable monthly video subscription fee. They show how to do OAUTH calls and fetch information from 3rd party providers on the federated logins to be included into user profiles. You can read the [code from the presentation](https://github.com/m2web/githublogin) freely but the video is still worthwhile.

The same calls they use could be used to set up any kind of information about users as they are created or, I suppose, to reject a user marked "supplier" who is using federated login.